# RxJS: waiting for a list of async operations to complete

Tags: amazon-s3, reactive-programming, rxjs

I have a collection of files that I am uploading to an s3 bucket, and I would like to use RxJS to execute some code when all of the uploads are complete.

My TypeScript method currently looks like this:

```
protected uploadToS3()
{
    this.uploader.queue.map( file => {
        this.appsService.uploadFileToS3( file,
            (filename) => console.log(`File: ${filename}`),
            (err) => console.log(`Error: ${err}`) ) ;
    });
}
```

Can anyone recommend a method in RxJS that will execute code once all of the `next()` methods have been called (the method that is accepting the `filename` parameter above)? I know I'm mixing styles of coding that really ought not be mixed together, but I have some legacy code that I must use.

Thanks!

Comment: how do you know when all the calls have been completed?

Comment: That's kinda what I'm asking.

Answer (score 0):

With some help from the people over at gitter, I came up with the following, which works:

```
var uploadFile = Observable.bindNodeCallback(this.appsService.uploadFileToS3);
var result = Observable.from(this.uploader.queue)
    .flatMap(e => uploadFile(e, this.authenticationService.apiKey));

result.subscribe(
    x => console.log(`Success: ${x}`),
    e => console.log(`Error: ${e}`),
    () => console.log(`Completed`)
);
```

Happy bunny.

M